# how to use bar code reader in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

I want to create windows application in c# that can work with bar code reader.

I want following feature to be add in my windows application:

-> Details of Product should be fill up automatically in form when bar code reader scanned correct bar code of product.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried?

Comment: Let us know how you go

Comment: This information is insufficient to find a solution to the problem and the request itself doesn't show any effort. I vote for too broad.

Comment: Barcode readers are recognized basically as keyboard input, usually with a line break at the end of the data. If you can build it for a keyboard then you can build it for a reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two types of bar code readers:

- working as keyboard input
- working on Serial Port

So the first one is really easy. Just plug in your reader to your computer, put the cursor on your TextBox and read barcode. As it works as keyboard input, the code will automatically fill your TextBox. There may be line break at the end of read (it depends on reader and/or its settings).

This works out of the box. The problem is that your textBox MUST HAVE focus.

Other type is ComPort. This is great if you want more functionality (or don't want to have focus on control). But needs more work. But C# has a class to do that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

You will need to set some things like baudrate, parity bits, port name (COM1, COM2, etc). It's more complicated but the question is about how to do it - not about COM ports. So I am not writing about COM ports.